# Apache forward https port 4434 to non https port on internal server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, svn, https

Im trying to set up a subversion edge server that is accessible from outside my network, I have one public IP and so the main webserver proxies to other internal server, i got the non https port (3343) to proxy to the internal server but i cant get the https port (4434) to proxy to the internal server http port (3343), I set apache to listen for https on port 4434 and I can telnet to that port on the main webserver but when it tries to proxy to the internal server it times out

heres what my apache virtualhost is for that proxy

VirtualHost *:4434

ServerName sub.domain.com

```
    SSLEngine On
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    ProxyRequests Off
            <Proxy *>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://ipofinternalserver:3343/
```

VirtualHost

Comment: Can you clarify "times out"?  Does your browser display a timeout message, or do you get an error response for a proxy timeout from Apache?

Comment: it says this web page is not available because ipofinternalserver took too long to respond

Comment: Sounds like you got redirected, then?  Did the URL in your address bar change to be the internal server's address?

Comment: Yes and even the correct port and URL but that error message comes up on the screen

Comment: Well, let me clarify; if the address bar has changed to the internal IP, then that's wrong.  The client browser should talk only to the proxy, and never to the server behind it; if a redirect has sent you away from the proxy then that's a bad thing.  Try adding a `ProxyPassReverse / http://ipofinternalserver:3343/` right with your existing `ProxyPass`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try iptables redirect 
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to -port 4443